# getting value from hidden textarea with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to retrieve the value of a textarea box that was initially hidden but when a checkbox is ticked it reveals the textbox for input. I have posted my code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RF5PK/

many thanks

Comment: The jsfiddle code doesn't work.

Comment: Why is the click show/hide listener for that textarea inside the listener for the submit button?

Comment: @Phil: just add a submit button and switch to jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/kvetk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, using [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$('textarea[name="setmessage"]').val();
```

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/ad3ND/).

<s>Although, from the code sample, I get the impression there's more to this question than meets the eye!</s>

Comment: @bollo: I figured as you were already using `val()` all over the place that that couldn't possibly be the right answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('textarea[name="setmessage"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/RF5PK/4/ see this i have only used needed jquery for your question. And I have added  contactmessage class to your text area.

Comment: The surrounding `div` already has the `contactmessage` class, I think his event listener was just in the wrong place.